# NameValuePair sort

Tags: java, apache

How can I sort `NameValuePair` objects like this by key

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(7)

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("api_key", "1"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("merchant", "4"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("format", "json"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("method", method));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cid", "0"));
```

Comment: Please specify the type of `nameValuePairs`

Comment: List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 8 you can use

```
Collections.sort(pairs, Comparator.comparing(NameValuePair::getName));
```

Answer (score 13):

Pass in the Comparator which sorts two `NameValuePair`s by key. Something like

```
Comparator<NameValuePair> comp = new Comparator<NameValuePair>() {        // solution than making method synchronized
    @Override
    public int compare(NameValuePair p1, NameValuePair p2) {
      return p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
    }
}

// and then
Collections.sort(pairs, comp);
```